# Decrease space between number in ordered list and text HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have an ordered list in an HTML email. It looks fine on browser of course but Outlook the spacing between the number and the text is absolutely massive. How can I reduce that spacing? As this is an Outlook email, **negative margins cannot be used and neither can tags like ::before and ::after.** If I don't use an ordered list (my first thought), **the text will not flow nicely on mobile** ie it will go under the number instead of the text on mobile screens.

Here is my code.

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="63%" class="list">

                    <tr>

                      <td style="text-align: center;" class="listpad">
                        <div style="color: #323840; font-family: 'Inter-Medium','Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
                        letter-spacing: -0.25px;  line-height: 24px; text-align: left;">
                          <ol>
                            <li>Click the blue circle with the question mark icon.</li>
                            <li>Select Contact Us from the menu.</li>
                            <li>Click on Live Chat.</li>
                          </ol>
                        </div>
                      </td>



                    </tr>

                  </table>
```

This is what it should look like:
[image: Correct spacing]

What it looks like in Outlook:
[image: Outlook]

Thanks for any help you can provide. Needless to say, I am very much looking forward to the new PWA Outlook. Maybe all of us email developers will regain some sort of sanity.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem by doing the following

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="63%" class="list">

                    <tr> 
                      
                      <td align="left" style="color: #323840; font-family: 'Inter-Medium','Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
                      letter-spacing: -0.22px;  line-height: 20px; text-align: left; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                       
                        <ol>
                          <li class="listpad">Click the blue circle with the question mark icon</li>
                          <li>Select <span style="font-family: 'Inter-Bold','Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" class="bld">Contact Us</span> from the menu.</li>
                          <li>Click on <span style="font-family: 'Inter-Bold','Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" class="bld">Live Chat.</span></li>
                        </ol>
                       
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    

                  </table>
```

Then in the head, you have to write this. I was surprised this working because negative values **don't** usually in Outlook:

```
<!--[if mso]> 
    <style>
    
    li {
      text-align:-webkit-match-parent; 
      display:list-item;
      text-indent: -1em;
    }
     
    ul, ol {    
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

 

    
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

I hope this helps some other poor email developer soul out there!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I've always found it tremendously difficult to get lists to work accurately across Outlook (like many others). Sadly, I suggest that you revert to coding like it's 1999.

**Recommended:** Ditch the `<ol>` and `<ul>` and go for the table layout:

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="63%" class="list">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;" class="listpad">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="color: #323840; font-family: 'Inter-Medium','Inter', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: -0.25px;  line-height: 24px; text-align: left; padding-left: 24px;">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="14" align="left">1.</td>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0.15em;" ;>
            Click the blue circle with the question mark icon.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="14" align="left">2.</td>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0.15em;" ;>
            Select Contact Us from the menu.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="14" align="left">3.</td>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0.15em;" ;>
            Click on Live Chat.
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could opt for something like `text-indent` as seen here on [caniemail](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=text-indent), but like most Outlook fixes, you would **need** to wrap it in conditional code to prevent it from causing issues on the web or other email clients...

```html
<!--[if mso]>
  <ol>
    <li style="text-indent: -14px;">Click the blue circle with the question mark icon.</li>
    <li style="text-indent: -14px;">Select Contact Us from the menu.</li>
    <li style="text-indent: -14px;">Click on Live Chat.</li>
  </ol>
<![endif]-->
```

In the image below (taken in Outlook 365),

1. Default `<ol>`
2. `text-indent` - Oddly, the **numbers** move, not the main text (as you might expect).
3. Swapped `<ol>` for the table approach (code above)

[image: Preview of code in Outlook]